# python pexpect connected to server how to get the exact output of commands

Tags: python, pexpect

In python I am connecting to a different server using

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh username@systemname')
```

once it is connected, I would like to execute some other commands. how to get the exact output of other child commands like?

```
 child.sendline("hostname")
```

or Let me know if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following and it would write to the filename mentioned:

```
child.sendline('hostname')
child.logfile_read = open("<filename>", 'a')
child.expect('<what ever you expect after the command execution>')
```